# Raspberry Pi: My agent installed successfully but I don't see it running on VOLTTRON

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, volttron

I am so happy to see that my newly created agent called RaspberryGPIOAgent was installed on the VOLTTRON without any errors. It was a success for me after working so many days on it. Moreover, I am beginner to the VOLTTRON. Presently I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3 B model. Here is the screenshot of the status of installing and starting this newly created agent. Yes! it installed and seems to have started but I don't see it running and health being GOOD. Don't know why and where and how to fix this issue? I appreciate your help.

The RaspberryGPIOAgent goal is: talk to a remote MySql server, get data, and generate analog output signals at its physical pins and control the devices connected to it.

[image]